# Element not shown in Firefox, but ok in other navigators

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a problem with a slideshow I coded.
It worked fine before, the website is online since january.
The problem is only when using Firefox 46, other navigators are displaying the elements.

The page with the slideshow : http://www.rotin-file.com/en/accueil

8 buttons appears, in the debugger I can see the 8  containing background images of products, and the absolute  containing the title, reference and price, but it doesn't appear in the website...

I tried to change many css properties (with the debugger) to find from where the problem comes (z-index, visibility, display, opacity, ...) but I can't understand why it's ok with Chrome and IE but not ok when using FireFox...

I verified all plugins are desactivated (also adblock is disabled for the whole domain) and tried on other computers with firefox, it never work with it...

Any idea to help me ?

Sorry for my bad english, and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to do, first remove:

```
#slideProduits #cntSlide {
    perspective: 1200px;
}
```

Second, you need z-index for your pager, so add:

```
#ctlSlide {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

But why it does not work in FF46, I have no idea. Guess 'cause [css perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) is still an 'experimental technology'.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the css perspective property the origin of the problem.

Comment: The weird thing is that I have many other websites with perspective property and it works well as this one : http://www.mightyprods.com/

Comment: But it works, and perspective is not necessary in this case. Thank you very much !

Comment: and also, you were right too, the z-index was bad on ctlSlide.